# How to fix "ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pip

I’m trying to import beautifulsoup but when I run the script I’m getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LinkCrawler.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "/Users/ivanyurchenko/Documents/Projects/crawler/bs4/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry
  File "/Users/ivanyurchenko/Documents/Projects/crawler/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 294, in <module>
    from . import _htmlparser
  File "/Users/ivanyurchenko/Documents/Projects/crawler/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from html.parser import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError'
```

I've tried to install/update beautifulsoup package but no joy:

```
$ pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
Requirement already up-to-date: beautifulsoup4 in /Users/ivanyurchenko/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages


$ python3 -m pip install -U beautifulsoup4
Requirement already up-to-date: beautifulsoup4 in /Users/ivanyurchenko/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

I’m not very familiar with python. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

UPD: I need a webcrawler so I've found an example project on github and am trying to make it work now. You can see its code [here](https://github.com/tarunbansal/crawler/blob/master/LinkCrawler.py).

Comment: It might help to see the script(s) causing the error.

Comment: where is your script file? on desktop?

Comment: @ScottHunter Please, check my updated question.

Comment: @DRPK No, it’s in my folder, I removed it from second code segment to make it more readable. The full line for update command actually looks like this: `MacBook-Pro:crawler ivanyurchenko$ pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: whats your ide? pycharm? your script file is a scratch file?